# 100 процентный, уникальный uuid в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, случайные-числа, uuid

Мне нужно сохранять много файлов на сервере и имена для этих файлов выбираются рандомно. Нашёл пост на stack overflow, в котором предлагают для такой задачи использовать `uuid4`. По определению в документации это совершено случайный UUID, т.е. чисто теоретически в течение большого количества времени, когда звёзды сойдутся, а венера зайдёт в третий круг, значение может повториться. Очень бы не хотелось, чтобы оно повторилось и какой-либо файл был перезаписан. Я конечно разделяю файлы по папкам по году, месяцу и дню, но всё же. Хочу использовать `uuid1`. В документации говорится, что он генерируется из идентификатора хоста, порядкового номера и текущего времени.

**Вопрос**: Возможно ли при такой конфигурации получить одинаковое значение? Не понятно, что понимается под текущем временем (с какой точностью берётся время?) и под порядковым номером. Это порядковый номер в цикле? В скрипте? Где? Если я перезапущу сервер, порядковый номер сбросится?

Comment: До этого «число теоретически» сначала наступит тепловая смерть вселенной. Но если вам мало этого, то кто мешает пойти по пути git и именовать файлы не рандомно, а по sha256 от их содержимого

Comment: @AlexeyTen простого содержимого может быть мало. Смотря что за файлы и насколько они большие, но совпадения и там вероятны.

Comment: Единственный способ получить строго-уникальный идентификатор - централизованный генератор и автоинкремент ;-)

Comment: Ну это уже две тепловых смерти вселенной ждать придётся. В общем, ни один рандомный способ по определению не даст 100% гарантии.

Comment: @AlexeyTen не совсем. Я конечно не знаком с данными автора, но мне кажется у него совпадение содержимого файлов вполне может случаться. Так что просто хэш - плохая идея. Надо его чем-то солить, типа метки времени или т.п.

Comment: @AlexeyTen есть 100% способ, это проверять: нет ли файла с таким именем в директории, но это лишние действия и время, мне казалось можно без этого обойтись)

Comment: Ладно, вы меня убедили, буду использовать uuid4 и надеяться, что разгневанный пользователь не прибежит ко мне со словами где моя картинка)

Comment: А теперь мы учтем, что требование направлено на непотерю файлов ... и подумаем о том, что риск того, что накроется даже 4-дисковый рейд, выше, чем коллизия, в невообразимое число раз ;-)

Comment: госпади, да у вам иноды на диске закончатся раньше, чем чтото из вышеописанного произойдёт!

Comment: А, понятно зачем uuid'ы: это попытка создать фотобанк всех котиков в интрнете...

Comment: @Kromster если два файла совпали побайтово и у них получился одинаковый хэш, то это же хорошо — сэкономили на диске =)

Comment: @AlexeyTen это хорошо до времени. А потом я свою картинку с котиком удалю, и ваша тоже пропадет, т.к. совпадала побайтово )))

Comment: Можете ещë посмотреть в сторону nanoid https://github.com/puyuan/py-nanoid. Он короче uuid, но комбинаций возможно больше.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Уникальность не гарантируется.

Текущее время [согласно спецификации](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122#section-4.1.4) берется с точностью до 100-наносекунд:

> The timestamp is a 60-bit value.  For UUID version 1, this is
> represented by Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) as a count of 100-
> nanosecond intervals since 00:00:00.00, 15 October 1582 (the date of
> Gregorian reform to the Christian calendar).

Порядковый номер по задумке авторов RFC - это способ бороться с дубликатами, которые могут возникнуть в результате перевода времени назад. Задумка была, чтобы при каждом переводе времени назад (или при перезагрузке, когда перевод мог случится когда ОС об этом не знала) увеличивать этот номер на 1. Но создатели стандартной библиотеки питона пошли своим путем. Порядковый номер можно самому передать в параметре `clock_seq` в вызов `uuid1`, а если не передать, то он генерируется случайно и при длине номера в 14 бит имеем всего 2^14 вариантов.

Comment: Ваше сообщение является ответом на мой вопрос, но справедливости ради отмечу. В итоге я всё-таки использовал `uuid4` вместе с текущем временем в миллисекундах. Я не знаю, что должно произойти, чтобы эти показатели совпали